# SQL: Conditional AND in where

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that allows parameters to be omitted, but ANDed if they are provided:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
    MyProcedure

    @LastName Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @FirstName Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @SSN INT = NULL
AS

SELECT LastName, FirstName, RIGHT(SSN,4) as SSN
FROM Employees
WHERE 
    (
        (LastName like '%' + ISNULL(@LastName, '') + '%')
            AND 
        (FirstName like '%' + ISNULL(@FirstName, '') + '%')
    )
AND
    (SSN = @SSN)
```

I only want to do the AND if there's an @SSN provided.  Or is there some other way to do this?

If an SSN is provided, all records are returned by the LastName/FirstName part of the query.  If just a lastname/firstname is provided, the AND makes it so no records are returned since the SSN won't validate.

Ideas?

---

Additional Clarification

Assume a basic recordset:

```
First          Last          SSN  
Mike           Smith         123456789  
Tom            Jones         987654321
```

IF we ALTER the Procedure above so it doesn't include this chunk:

```
AND
    (SSN = @SSN)
```

then everything works great, provided we're passed a FirstName or LastName.  But I want to be able to include SSN, if one is provided.

If I change the AND to an OR, then I get a bad result set since the FirstName/LastName portion of the query evalute to:

```
WHERE (LastName like '%%' and FirstName like '%%')
```

(which will, of course, return all records)

---

If I can't conditionally abort the AND, I'm hoping for something like:

```
AND
    (SSN like ISNULL(@SSN, '%'))
```

:-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change:

```
AND (SSN = @SSN)
```

to:

```
AND (SSN = @SSN or @SSN is null)
```

If `SSN` is never null, you could also do:

```
AND SSN = ISNULL(@SSN, SSN)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return null SSNs when a value has been provided?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to check "is null" first for short circuiting?

Comment: Actually wouldn't you want to do something like "AND ((SSN is not null AND SSN = @SSN) OR (@SSN is null))"

Comment: @Benjamin re: short-circuit, depends on which parameter signature is most common. I doubt there is any signficant difference in performance either way.

Comment: @Benjamin *wouldn't you want to do something like...* - why?

Comment: I updated my question since I didn't explain it well enough... My apologies. I want to be able to pass this stored procedure any of the values and get the proper results.  The SSN isn't so much the issue - except that if one is provided, I get ALL records because of the First/Last part of the WHERE.  I want to include the SSN part of the WHERE only if it's provided.  :-)

Comment: @RussellSchutte I believe my answer is still valid. If not, please provide sample data, examples of calling the SP with parameters, and desired output.

Comment: @RedFilter, thanks for helping. The AND is the issue... It would work fine with an OR... but I want to use an AND in this query so I'm matching on Name and SSN if they are both provided.  (I don't want to use AND if the SSN is the only value provided... because the name search will return all names if no name is provided - it evaluates to Firstname like '%%'  (with nothing between the percentages).

Comment: @RussellSchutte *the name search will return all names if no name is provided* - this is incorrect, provdiding just a non-null SSN param will filter the results to just those matching SSN.

Comment: @RedFilter - I tried to provide Additional Clarification above.  Hopefully it makes sense.  The entire AND clause is my issue.

Comment: Bmo, below, understands my challenge - I could do an IF SSN is not NULL run Select1, if not run Select2.  That'd work, but I actually have several parameters I want to handle in this fashion and it seems like an inelegant approach.  Is there a better one?

Comment: @RussellSchutte I'm pretty sure you don't understand my answer. Why don't you tell me what you think it does.

Comment: @RedFilter, you're right on...  I didn't understand the "if SSN is is never NULL," so I hadn't followed through that part...  Your solution works perfectly, I just didn't understand the text around it.  Your first solution works for VARCHAR fields while the second version works for INT fields.  I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I like that. I was hoping case when wouldn't be involved as I have used it for some conditional stuff in the past

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
(ISNULL(SSN, @SSN) = @SSN)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, diana...  but the AND is my issue - not how to provide a missing value for SSN.  Please see my added edits to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could put both versions of the statement in an if block.

```
 AS
 IF @SSN IS NULL
      /*regular statement*/
 ELSE
      /*Statement with @SSN*/
```

or

```
 AND
      SSN = ISNULL(@SSN, SSN)
```

I have never used the 2nd option but I know it exists.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Bmo...  but the AND is my issue - not how to provide a missing value for SSN.  Please see my added edits to the question.

Comment: Then the first option checks to see if an SSN got passed. If it does it runs the SELECT without the AND, if an SSN did get passed it would run the SELECT with the AND.

Comment: So two completely seperate selects is the only way to do this?  That seems like one way to do it - but it's very wordy when I actually have a few other potential parameters that could be passed.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the only way to do it. It's just all that I can think of. I'm fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE's THE BIBLE](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) on dynamic search parameters in SQL Server. You should write it like this

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, RIGHT(SSN,4) as SSN
FROM Employees
WHERE (NULLIF(@LastName,'') IS NULL OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%')
  AND (NULLIF(@FirstName,'') IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
  AND (@SSN is null or SSN = @SSN)
   -- or if not provided means blank, then
   -- (@SSN = '' or SSN = @SSN)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

BTW, there's no such thing as a short circuit boolean in SQL Server.  Yes it does stop at the first conclusion, but there's no guarantee the condition on the left is processed before the right.  e.g. this code is **NOT SAFE**.  I'm using 'ABC.123' but that could just as well be a column.

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC('ABC.123') = 1 OR CAST('ABC.123' AS INT) > 10
```

To illustrate on the `AND (@SSN is null or SSN = @SSN)` clause, for when @SSN is not provided, i.e. NULL

```
   AND (@SSN is null or SSN = NULL)
=> AND (NULL IS NULL or SSN = NULL)
=> AND (TRUE or SSN = NULL)
=> AND (TRUE)

-- In other words, this filter is "dissolved" and appears as if it never existed.
-- (in the scheme of a series of AND conditions)
```

Comment: Richard, thanks for helping.  The note about no guarantee which side is processed first is very interesting, I don't think I've ever counted on it, but it's good to know that I shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
    MyProcedure

    @LastName Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @FirstName Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @SSN INT = -1
AS

SELECT LastName, FirstName, RIGHT(SSN,4) as SSN
FROM Employees
WHERE 
    (
        (LastName like '%' + ISNULL(@LastName, '') + '%')
            AND 
        (FirstName like '%' + ISNULL(@FirstName, '') + '%')
    )
AND
    (SSN = @SSN or @SSN = -1)
```

Just give @SSN a default value and you can use the AND all the time and worry about it.