# Using a stored procedure with T-SQL IF/ELSE in C# with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use this stored procedure in a C# project, where the parameters that I send are used to determine which kind of SQL query is going to be used, but while trying to refresh the datasource in C#, it never returns any record:

```
IF(@productName = '' AND @productCode = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
END
ELSE IF (@productName <> '' AND @productCode = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
     AND a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO LIKE '%' + @productName + '%'
END
ELSE IF (@productName = '' AND @productCode <> '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
     AND a.COD_PRODUCTO = @productCode
END
```

END

Is it possible to use the parameters like that? the parameters work if the IF/ELSE is not being used, but I need to do it that way in order to alter the query based on the needs, unless there's a better option, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm confused... If this is a stored procedure, then doesn't the C# code just call the stored procedure itself?  Why does the code *within* the stored procedure make a difference from the C# code's perspective?

Comment: It is faster to try it than asking here, however yes they (the parameters) should work as expected. It doesn't matter how do you use those parameters in the stored procedure. Just pass them

Comment: I'm calling the stored procedure from the Datasource config wizard, when I try to test it, I get an error saying that no record has been returned, however if I test the stored procedure in SQL server, it works great. The stored procedure in C# was working fine before including the IF/ELSE with the new parameters, but now is not, that's why I'm wodering if C# supports that kind of evaluation with params. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Use `NULL` to represent a missing or absent value (including parameter value), do not use special values (including empty string). 2) read http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion i would create three different stored procedures. The code your have written currently will work but not safe in the future.

In future developments you will most likely re-write the code again because it is not dynamic.

In that why you can move your if else statements on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to keep your solution simple. If/ELSE statement is preventing your code from working? Just get rid of that trying a different approach. Maybe it´s better to keep just one select block, you can still identify which option is the current with NRO_QUERY value, and that value, as any of the optative ones, can be easily checked for valid value if you manipulate the result in C#.
Here´s my suggestion:

```
BEGIN  
SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO,   
a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO,   
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,   
CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL,   
CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,  
b.TIPO_CLIENTE,  
b.NUM_EMPRESA  
FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b  
ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO  
AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA  
AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType  
AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')  
AND a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO LIKE '%' + @productName + '%'  
AND a.COD_PRODUCTO = @productCode  
CASE  
WHEN (@productName = '' AND @productCode = '') THEN 1  
WHEN (@productName <> '' AND @productCode = '') THEN 2   
WHEN (@productName = '' AND @productCode <> '') THEN 3  
END AS NRO_QUERY  
END
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding these **AND a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO LIKE '%' + @productName + '%' AND a.COD_PRODUCTO = @productCode** as "AND" clauses because not all the times these parameters are going to be used.

Comment: Maybe this idea can help:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845191/sql-conditional-and-in-where

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in stored procedures and C#, somehow, this:

```
(@productName <> '' AND @productCode = '')
```

was not working properly, so instead of doing that, I defaulted the values to NULL instead of '' and did this:

```
IF(@productName IS NULL AND @productCode IS NULL)
```

And it retrieves data in C# now, I don't see logic on it, but it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you forgive the pass parameter value that time it take auto null

then we have two solution over here.

1st is define default '' (blank)

```
@productName nvarchar(255) = ''
```

2nd You should check it null or not if it null then change to ''(blank).

```
IF(isnull(@productName,'') = '' AND isnull(@productCode,'') = '')
```

try this code :

```
IF(isnull(@productName,'') = '' AND isnull(@productCode,'') = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
END
ELSE IF(isnull(@productName,'') <> '' AND isnull(@productCode,'') = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
     AND a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO LIKE '%' + @productName + '%'
END
ELSE IF(isnull(@productName,'') = '' AND isnull(@productCode,'') <> '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.COD_PRODUCTO, 
                    a.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
                    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), b.PRECIO_UNITARIO) AS PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_DISPONIBL) AS UNIDADES_DISPONIBL, 
                    CONVERT(INT, a.UNIDADES_TRANSITO) AS UNIDADES_TRANSITO,
                    b.TIPO_CLIENTE,
                    b.NUM_EMPRESA
    FROM sysadm.IN_PRODUCTOS a INNER JOIN sysadm.IN_PRECIOS_TIPOCLT b
      ON a.COD_PRODUCTO = b.COD_PRODUCTO
     AND a.NUM_EMPRESA = b.NUM_EMPRESA
     AND b.TIPO_CLIENTE = @ClientType
     AND B.NUM_EMPRESA NOT IN('50', '60')
     AND a.COD_PRODUCTO = @productCode
END
```